Validity of work-around to fit power curve for mixed-sign data
I have data for a system that is generally accepted to follow a power law, but my data is for both positive or negative values. Typically one only collects data for positive or negative values, and fits the curve to that data (using the absolute value if working with negative data). My question is: How (in)appropriate is it to fit my curve to the absolute values of my full set of mixed-sign data?

Do you believe the power index should be the same for both positive and negative values?

@Glen_b Good question. Yes, I would. And after comparing the output of another tool doing the same analysis for positive inputs versus negative inputs, they do align. So I guess that answers that, I should be fine do to work with the absolute values of the full set.
Although there is a subtle nuance, uncovered when making that comparison. One of the inputs is a relative measurement, and the absolute reference is also provided. The inputs need to be offset to take the absolute reference into account for a non-zero reference to yield the same results.

I do expect the same equation for positive or negative inputs, the only thing that should change is the sign of the output, which is easy enough to account for. This has been corroborated with other implementations, so I should be okay to do what I propose.
However, I uncovered some subtle nuance for this particular usage after comparing the outputs for positive versus negative inputs of another tool doing the same analysis. One of the inputs is a relative measurement, but we also have an absolute reference. The relative inputs need to be offset to take the absolute reference into account for a non-zero reference to yield the same results for both positive and negative inputs.
(Similar to comment above because I ran into the comment edit timeout, but this is also a bit more thorough)
